# CentOS Server connectivity problem

Tags: centos, networking, nagios

I have deployed a Nagios Core solution for my company, an ISP, to monitor customer's network devices (hosts).

It is running on CentOS 7 as a Virtual Machine running on a physical server.

However, I am very frequently disconnected from the server when connected via SSH using VS Code, once every 5 minutes or less, and Nagios alerts me for network devices that are supposedly down whereas in reality they are not.

I also noticed that in the scope of a minute, every host check that is supposed to run during the said minute fails, and the same checks the very next minute succeeds.
This can happen several times an hour and it clogs Nagios' log files.

So I followed a guide on how to troubleshoot basic network issues on CentOS:

https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/beginners-guide-network-troubleshooting-linux

However, nothing seems out of the ordinary.

Now for the mysterious part: when opening a cmd from my PC running on Windows 10, connecting via ssh by typing:

```
# ssh user@server_address
```

Then typing my password and finally running:

```
# ping gateway_address
```

So in other words permanently pinging the server's physical gateway from the cmd, which translates to the server permanently pinging its gateway, I am no more disconnected when working on the server via VS Code SSH and moreover, Nagios' host checks return to normal and alert me only when a host is really down.

If I stop the ping from the cmd, the problem returns but as long as the ping is running, the problem vanishes.

I tried to use the:

```
# nohup ping gateway_address &
```

command to run a ping permanently in the background, but as long as the cmd is not open actively pinging the gateway, the problem persists.

As for the network architecture, the server has to go through that gateway to reach the hosts Nagios is monitoring.

Do you have any idea of what is happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: It might help name some of the hosts, even generically, like CentOSVM and PhysicalHost, so that troubleshooting at each layer is as clear as possible.

Comment: Already done! I'll be happy to provide you with any information I can, but keep in mind I'm just an intern for that company so some information may not be accessible

Comment: That "via VS Code SSH" sticks to my eye a bit... Do you experience the same issues if you go in the standard way `ssh user@system`?

Comment: Yes exactly! Unless I ping the gateway, using the standard cmd for ssh, putty or vs code, the connection is lost at some point.